# How to use Composer to autoload classes from outside the vendor?

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload

I use `psr-4` autoloader from composer:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "DG\\Munchkin\\": "src/DG/Munch/"
    }
}
```

This loads classes from `/var/www/html/xxx/vendor/yyy/src/DG/Munch`

But how can I load classes from `/var/www/html/xxx/`?

I wrote my own autoloader, but when I require `vendor/autoload.php` (composer autoload) and my autoloader, it won't work until I create instance of a class in my own autoloader.

Comment: Can't you simply use the `files` or `classmap` autoloader? https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#autoload

Comment: Yup, files or classmap should do the trick.

Comment: No, because i can't select folders from outside vendor folder in autoload section.

Comment: I need composer to autoload classes by absolute path (not by patch IN vendor directory).

Comment: "This loads classes from..." not it does not making this question impossible to answer, because it is based on incorrect assumptions.

Comment: Why should any package reference classes that are not part of that package? What if that package is used in another context where such classes are not defined?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The `src` directory would be in your project root.
Its on the same level as `vendor` directory is.

If you define

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "DG\\Munchkin\\": "src/DG/Munch/"
    }
}
```

this will not load classes from `/var/www/html/xxx/vendor/yyy/src/DG/Munch`,
like you stated.

Because your project structure is:

```
/var/www/html/
 +- /xxx (project)
     - composer.json
     +- /src
        +- DG
           +- Munch
     +- /vendor
        - autoload.php
        +- vendor-projectA
        +- vendor-projectB
        +- yyy
```

The `\DG\Munchkin` namespace would map to classes inside

`/var/www/html/xxx/src/DG/Munch` and not inside

`/var/www/html/xxx/vendor/yyy/src/DG/Munch`.

**But how can I load classes from /var/www/html/xxx/?**

Define the paths in the composer.json (inside /var/www/html/xxx/) of your project:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "ProjectRoot\\" : "", 
        "NamspaceInSourceDir\\" : "src/"         
    }
 }
```

or load the composer autoloader in your index.php or during it's bootstrap and add the paths manually:

```
$loader = require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$loader->add('Namespace\\Somewhere\\Else\\', __DIR__);
$loader->add('Namespace\\Somewhere\\Else2\\', '/var/www/html/xxx');
```

Referencing: https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#autoload