# include external php files(not in laravel directory) in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I want to include an external PHP file into my service provider, that file is in a different folder. 
Like my file is in folder1 and this folder is at same level as laravel is.

```
   C:\xampp\htdocs\registration\php\file.php //this is file
   C:\xampp\htdocs\_problem_sharing\app\AppServiceProvider
```

This is how I am trying right now

```
include_once "/../../../registration/php/user_info.php";
```

Comment: Going two level back: `include_once "../../registration/php/user_info.php";` should be enought. Also, don't prepend the relative path with `/`.

Comment: its still looking the file under Providers directory @Bogdan

Comment: What's the error that you're getting?

Comment: `FatalErrorException in AppServiceProvider.php line 14:
Class 'App\Providers\UserInfo' not found` where UserInfo is my class name in the file that I am trying to include. @Bogdan this happens when I try to make class object `$this->userInfo = new UserInfo();`

Comment: Since the provideo is in it's own namespace `App\Providers`, you should either put this at the top of your provideor class file `use UserInfo`, or whenever using the class inside the code prepend it with a backslash which puts it in the global namespace (for ex: `new \UserInfo()`). If the problem persists, please post the contents of your provider.

Comment: @Bogdan please refer  to this [gist](https://gist.github.com/waqasraza123/3e16e23904e31d419722)

Answer (score 1):

Is really simple to do this. Because everything in Laravel 5 is autoloaded using PSR-4, within the app/ directory. So, for example, if this file you want to include have a class.

You need to create the directory, e. g.: `app/CustomStuff/CustomDirectory/`
Into this directory, create the file: `app/CustomStuff/CustomDirectory/SomeClass.php`

Into the SomeClass.php file, you just need:

```
<?php 
namespace App\CustomStuff\CustomDirectory;

class Someclass {}
```

Now, you can access this class using the namespace within your classes:

```
use App\CustomStuff\CustomDirectory\SomeClass;
```

Comment: i do not want to copy that file into laravel's directory

Comment: I think that's not possible, you have to copy the file into Laravel

Comment: @VitorLuis Of course it's possible, you can load any file from anywhere in the filesystem as long as you have permission to read it, you just need to use `include` or `require`, or if you want to you autoload it using Composer, you need [to configure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28253154/how-to-i-use-composer-to-autoload-classes-from-outside-the-vendor) `composer.json`.

Comment: You could symlink the file into laravel, this will ensure the file is tracked by git as well.