# Composer - autoload classes in CodeIgniter outside vendor folder

Tags: php, codeigniter, composer-php, autoload

I've been working on setting up a CodeIgniter project with composer.  I'm wanting to include `php` classes stored in files outside the `vendor` folder - in a `shared` folder.

My directory structure:

```
/
  --application/
  --shared/
    -application/
       -class1.php
       -class2.php
       -class3.php
    -base/
       -classb1.php
  --vendor/
  --composer.json
  --composer.lock
```

Looking at the composer [documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#autoload), I see there is an `autoload` property in the root package that I'm trying to use to load the classes in the `shared` directory.  These classes aren't namespaced.

My `composer.json` file is as follows:

```
{
    "description" : "The CodeIgniter Application with Composer",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.2",
        "codeigniter/framework": "3.1.*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "mikey179/vfsStream": "1.1.*"
    },
    "autoload":{
       "psr-0":{
           "":"shared/application/",
           "":"shared/base/",
           "":"shared/data/"
        }
    }
}
```

My search led me to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28253154/how-to-i-use-composer-to-autoload-classes-from-outside-the-vendor), but the classes are still not being loaded.  I've ran `composer update` on the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Well after looking further, there's a property called `classmap` ([documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#classmap)) in the root package.

```
"autoload":{
    "classmap":["shared/application/","shared/base/", "shared/data/"]
}
```

This loads all the required files in the folders.