# Install framework outside vendor folder

Tags: php, github, frameworks, composer-php, web-frameworks

I build a php framework. I want to add to composer so I can install it via

```
composer require muratyavuz2/testphp
```

But when I run this command it install inside vendor folder. I want to install same folder and create vendor folder.

How can I do that

NOTE: packages and accounts are for test only.

Comment: Have a look at the command create-project of composer: https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#create-project it will alow you to install your project in a given directory then install all these own dependencies

Comment: Perhaps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28285201/3392762